# Como eu altero multiplos objetos dentro de um Array

Tags: javascript, array, react

Preciso converter esse `time_h` decimal para `horas : minutos` por exemplo 5.75 = 5:45
Mas esse array tem mais de 150 objetos, como faço para iterar e converter todos os valores?

```
const usinaData = [
  {
    time_h: 5.333333333333333,
    tensao_V: 550.9,
    corrente_A: 0,
    potencia_kW: 0,
    temperatura_C: 26.2
  },
  {
    time_h: 5.416666666666667,
    tensao_V: 623.2,
    corrente_A: 0,
    potencia_kW: 0,
    temperatura_C: 29.1
  },
  {
    time_h: 5.5,
    tensao_V: 635,
    corrente_A: 0,
    potencia_kW: 0.254,
    temperatura_C: 30.3
  },
  {
    time_h: 5.583333333333333,
    tensao_V: 578.2,
    corrente_A: 0,
    potencia_kW: 0.636,
    temperatura_C: 32.4
  },
  {
    time_h: 5.666666666666667,
    tensao_V: 577.7,
    corrente_A: 0,
    potencia_kW: 0.924,
    temperatura_C: 33.6
  },
  {
    time_h: 5.75,
    tensao_V: 612.7,
    corrente_A: 0,
    potencia_kW: 1.347,
    temperatura_C: 34.5
  }
]
```

Tenho essa conversão por enquanto mas isso não muda os valores no Data.

```
usinaData.filter(function(obj){
    var time = obj.time_h;
    const hours = Math.floor(obj.time_h);
    const decimal = time - hours;
    const minutes = Math.floor(decimal*60);
    const total = hours + ':' + minutes;
    console.log(total);
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode usar duas formas

Com `forEach` ou `map`

Exemplos

```js
const usinaData = [
    {
      time_h: 5.333333333333333,
      tensao_V: 550.9,
      corrente_A: 0,
      potencia_kW: 0,
      temperatura_C: 26.2
    },
    {
      time_h: 5.416666666666667,
      tensao_V: 623.2,
      corrente_A: 0,
      potencia_kW: 0,
      temperatura_C: 29.1
    },
    {
      time_h: 5.5,
      tensao_V: 635,
      corrente_A: 0,
      potencia_kW: 0.254,
      temperatura_C: 30.3
    },
    {
      time_h: 5.583333333333333,
      tensao_V: 578.2,
      corrente_A: 0,
      potencia_kW: 0.636,
      temperatura_C: 32.4
    },
    {
      time_h: 5.666666666666667,
      tensao_V: 577.7,
      corrente_A: 0,
      potencia_kW: 0.924,
      temperatura_C: 33.6
    },
    {
      time_h: 5.75,
      tensao_V: 612.7,
      corrente_A: 0,
      potencia_kW: 1.347,
      temperatura_C: 34.5
    }
  ]

  usinaData.forEach(obj => {
    var time = obj.time_h;
    const hours = Math.floor(obj.time_h);
    const decimal = time - hours;
    const minutes = Math.floor(decimal*60);
    const total = hours + ':' + minutes;
    obj.time_h = total;
  })

  console.log(usinaData);
```

ou

```
const usinaData1 = usinaData.map(obj => {
        var time = obj.time_h;
        const hours = Math.floor(obj.time_h);
        const decimal = time - hours;
        const minutes = Math.floor(decimal*60);
        const total = hours + ':' + minutes;
        obj.time_h = total;
        return obj
})
```